# Have lost Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ability to see/access Windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, samba

I have lost the ability to access the shared folders on my Windows 10 PC via WiFi from my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (64bit) laptop using Samba.

I can't ping the IP address, and does not appear as a device in GUI Settings/Network/Other Devices.

- My other Windows PC, and iOS computers can can still see and access these Windows folders/files with no problem.
- The Windows PC can still see and access my Ubuntu shared files as well.

It previously worked seamlessly.

I've looked, but can't find a walkthrough to assist me - where the rest of the network is communicating fine & only my Ubuntu device seems to be the problem. The links I've found don't cover this scenario. Looking through other similar questions, I've unsuccessfully tried adding `hosts: files wins dns` to the etc/nsswitch.conf file. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Further reading - I have been doing all my app edits using ```sudo gedit``` to fix my issues. Now "Networks" not even an option in Files>Locations. I've read this is bad way to edit. Could this be part of my problem... and if so, can someone talk me through how to undo these edits that are now root? thx, Boo (still a Noob apparently  :\  ) I've tried fully purging Samba and dependencies & reinstall with no luck.

Comment: Your goal is to make your question better, so use the EDIT button to do that instead of adding comments down here.